# Mono on OSX: Couldn't find gtksharpglue-2.dll

Tags: c#, macos, mono, gtk

I'm trying to do my first steps in C# and wanted to build an empty GTK window as my first task. Via `macports` I installed the following packages:

- mono@2.10.9
- gtk-sharp@1.0.10
- gtk-sharp2@2.12.10

I also use MonoDevelop from the Mono homepage.

I added `gtk-sharp.dll` (from `/opt/local/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0`) to my references.
My code looks like this:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace lolbr_client
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading..");
            Window window = new Window("test");
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run that snippet, it seems to find and include the GTK-library, it prints "Loading.." to the console, but the line after `Console.WriteLine()` causes this error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Container:gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset ()
  at Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

While that particular .dll doesn't exist on my filesystem, a quick `locate gtksharpglue-2` revealed the following files:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.so
/opt/local/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.a
/opt/local/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.la
/opt/local/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.so
```

Do those files help me? What are the next steps from here to debug/fix this? I already searched Google, but either I am too new to this subject to recognize useful information, or useful information just doesn't exist. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution how to run GTK Sharp MONO apps (compiled for example with Xamarin Studio) is to do following:

1. Compile your mono/gtk-sharp app as Release
2. Create shell script file (bash) like this (name it anyway you wish)

   ```
   [sharp]!/bin/sh

   export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib"    
   exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono ./AsketicExcel.exe
   ```

[image]

_3. Then you could run this form Terminal or you can use this packager tool http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus and create normal OSX App :) (include in the package all your files in Release dir)

Then in order to run this app on other mac you will need to install GTK# & Mono runtime http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

In the end it would look like:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have found the issue, my `dllmap` was incomplete.

I added the following lines to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/etc/mono/config`:

```
<dllmap os="osx" dll="libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="glibsharpglue-2" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libglibsharpglue-2.so" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="libgthread-2.0-0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="libgthread-2.0-0.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="libglib-2.0-0.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="libgobject-2.0-0.dll" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib" />
```

Comment: those dllmaps should already come with gtk-sharp, care to find the root cause of the issue so we fix it upstream for the next developer?

Comment: @knocte I will look into it. I sort of assumed that dependencies like `glib` would be already configured after installation, so maybe this is where the problem is. Are you a Mono or gtk-sharp developer?

Comment: Issue still present after 10 mounts, in version 3.2.3. Funny :\

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue aswell and although Fabian's answer was on the right track, it wasn't the solution for me. As per [this bug filed with Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4544#c3), the following entries to the `dllmap` were required to be added to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/etc/mono/config` (with a couple of duplicates removed).

```
<dllmap os="osx" dll="glibsharpglue-2" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libglibsharpglue-2.so" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gthread-2.0.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgthread-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gthread-2.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgthread-2.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="glib-2.0.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libglib-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="glib-2.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libglib-2.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="glibsharpglue-2" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libglibsharpglue-2.so" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gtksharpglue-2" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.so" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gobject-2.0.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgobject-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gobject-2.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgobject-2.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gtk-quartz-2.0.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib" />
<dllmap os="osx" dll="gtk-quartz-2.0" target="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.dylib" />
```