# Mono on OSX: Couldn't find gtksharpglue-2.dll when adding Gtk to existing console based program

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to add a GUI interface to an already existing program which outputs to console. I am developing in C# using OSX with Monodevelop.

I've run across a peculiar problem: When I try to add a GTK file and interface the program throws an exception that it can't find Gtkshrarpglue-2. I believe this problem is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885454/mono-on-osx-couldnt-find-gtksharpglue-2-dll), but I tried the supposed solution and it did not work for me. Furthermore, I'm looking for a fix where I can use debug build instead of release.

What's weird about this problem is that I can build a gtk GUI interface from scratch using Monodevelop, but I get the error when I try to add it to an existing program.

Any thoughts?