# Including GTK# Dlls with Statically Linked (mkbundle)Mono Exe on Mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, gtk, gtk#

I have an application coded in c# using the Mono Framework and GTK# for UI.Im trying to create a static bundle for MacOSX (including gtk# and mono runtime)

I just bundled Mono with my exe file using

```
mkbundle --static hello.exe -o --deps hello2.exe
```

I got the exe file but when i drag it and put it on the terminal i get `System.DllNotFound Exception:glibsharpglue-2`

I understand that i need to include the gtk# libraries.But i dont know how to do that with a statically linked mono runtime.Is there an option to do that using mkbundle.All i need to get is a final standalone package ready to run on Mac.

Please help me out.

UPDATE:
The shell script I'm currently using with Platypus to make the .app package

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib"    
exec /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono myapp.exe
```

Im currently using the option provided in platypus to include myapp.exe file.How can i include the dlls required for GTK? Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The error is from not finding the GTK shared object libraries (SO/dylib).

**Using `mkbundle`:**

If using 32-bit Mono you will need to assign the arch type for AS and CC. By default, clang will compile and link x86_64 which may not match your installed Mono's arch type.

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386 -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -liconv"

mkbundle gtkdesigner.exe --deps -o gtkdemo
```

The resulting executable will still require Mono (and any dependant shared objects/dylibs) to be installed.

Or adding `--static` to statically link to mono libs and thus invoking the LGPL of Mono (you will need to distribute your original CIL images so the user can upgrade the version of Mono that is running your app, unless you have a license from Xamarin)

```
mkbundle --static gtkdesigner.exe --deps -o gtkdemo
```

The resulting executable will not require Mono to be installed, but any dependant shared objects/dylibs will still be required.

**GTK/GTK# based applications:**

A GTK# based application will still require the GTK shared objects/dylibs to be installed and accessible by the resulting executable (i.e. gtkdemo in this case):

Thus if you try to run `./gtkdemo` it will need to find shared libraries such as libc.dylib, libgtksharpglue-2.so, etc, etc... otherwise the error you are getting will be shown.

Set the dylib library path to your GTK libraries, not the C# CIL binding library (GTK#), but the native shared object libraries. Since you have Mono installed on OS-X, it also installs its own version of GTK that can be found at `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib`. If you are installing your own version GTK to a different location just change the path to that location. You also will be to include the location of the OS's std C library.

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib:/usr/lib"
./gtkdemo
```

Note: You can package this `gtkdemo` application into a normal OS-X app by using a packager tool such as http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus. Package all the GTK libraries and any other required so/dylibs into the `app` and provide a shell script that assigns the DYLIB path in order to find those `app` based GTK libs. Then you can distribute the self-contained `app` and the end-user just double-clicks it to run you GTK-based app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Its been really helpful.I generated the statically linked exe.I also had to use export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.3/bin:$PATH to set the current mono path to correct an error occurred.I got the exe.I have used platypus early to create an app package with the exe(which does not contain mono or gtk#).The app package works great.I reffered this http://www.hitmaroc.net/405830-1762-mono-osx-couldn-find-gtksharpglue-dll.html . Im posting the shell script i have in my answer.Please tell me what should i include in the .app package to bundle gtk?

Comment: I do not have a list of gtk libs handy, but you can copy the gtk libs one-by-one from Mono's (/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib) to the local directory that contains your mkbundle built executable until it works (without a DYLIB path set), that it what I did to create a build script for OS-X. I use a mod'd version of bockbuild now...

Comment: Thanks.I have many folders in the lib directory there is gtk 2.0,gtk-sharp-2.0.Which files should i copy?Should i copy the folders too?

Comment: I'm not on an OS-X box right now, I think those directories are for things such as GTK cups based printing, etc.. so yes if your app needs them. Again, I just copied files one-by-one till my GTK app worked and used that list in my build script.

Comment: Can you please provide me with the list of files,when you can.It will be very much appreciated .I tried copying glibsharpglue-2.so and tried running the app by pulling it to the terminal i got the same error also i noticed this in the error --> mono myapp.exe
Cannot open assembly 'myapp.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.

Comment: Also i don't need printing.I use GTK just for the UI.

Comment: "myapp.exe"? is that the file created by mkbundle? If so, it is not a CIL image, it is a native os-x binary and thus you do not run it via Mono.

Comment: myapp.exe is created by mkbundle.To verify i just copied all the stuff from the lib dir(around 400mb) and put myapp.exe in there.I just dragged and dropped it into the terminal.Hurray! it works.Please provide me with the list of files if you have :) I will be waiting..

Comment: Personally I would rename "myapp.exe" as it is not an '.exe'. I'll see if I have a copy of that build script when I can, copying the entire lib directory works, but you only need the gtk and dependencies.

Comment: I referred this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885454/mono-on-osx-couldnt-find-gtksharpglue-2-dll and copied those dlls.Now the glibsharpglue exception is gone and i get > System.DllNotFoundException: libintl.dylib . I have copied libintl.dylib,libintl.8.dylib and libintl.8 82.dylib,still does not work.

Comment: Could you get access to the build script.Please help me out.Im stuck here

Comment: I have copied the whole lib dir and I'm trying to create a test package using platypus.I have VAR=```pwd```
echo "export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$VAR:/usr/lib"
./myapp I keep getting System.DllNotFoundException: libintl.dylib.But when i use cd desktop/lib and then ./myapp it works.What I'm doing wrong.Please advice.

Comment: How to use BockBuild? https://github.com/mono/bockbuild Can i use it to create a standalone app package with static mono?

Comment: You should look at Banshee's code if you have not done so already as that is where bockbuild originally come from in order to see how they build `.app` bundles...

Comment: I downloaded it.There are many folders and files inside src.Which one should i look.Is Bockbuild something like Bockbuild myapp.exe then i get a static mono linked native executable? I have successfully compiled the working native code.The thing is even though --static flag is used and after setting the DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH on execution the program is checking for libglib-2.0.dll in the Library/Framework folder.I tried adding the dllmap in the config file.Does not work.Is Mono Broken? Im tired of this.TONS AND TONS of Bugs in the IDE plus this.I dont know why people pay for Xamarin.Mac.

Comment: Banshee simply does not work on osx.the icon appears on the dock and goes away.I have tried 2 versions.Their launch script uses a local copy of mono and does not use a statically linked native executable.

Answer (score 0):

Since gkt# is an open-source library why not download the code?
You would need to install git and do:
git clone https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp

Then, you can reference those donwloaded gtk-sharp projects directly in your solution.

Note: i believe you still need the native OSXs gtk libraries since gtk-sharp is a wrapper of those libs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yeah im trying to include the native gtk libraries.But i dont know what files to include.See the answer above

Comment: I have just performed a search in gtk-sharps code for 'DllImports' and this seems to be the list of dlls used: libatk-1.0-0.dll
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
libgobject-2.0-0.dll
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll
libpango-1.0-0.dll
libglib-2.0-0.dll   hope this helps.

Comment: thanks i have included most of this.. but does not work.I need the whole gtk library.