# Mono error on Ubuntu: System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

I am trying to add a GTK# project to a Xamarin.Forms solution and run this GTK project on Linux.
For this I followed the steps mentioned in the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/gtk?tabs=windows

I build this solution with GTK libraries in VS-2017 on Win machine, and after build GTK Project is running on Win without errors.
Same GTK project when I try to run on Linux-Ubuntu16, it is giving below error.

---

```
spsuser@ubuntusrv:~/Desktop/Boxview/Debug$ sudo mono BasicBoxView.GTK.exe 

Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gtk.Container' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Container.gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset()
  at Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Gtk.Bin..ctor (System.IntPtr raw) [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
  at Gtk.Window..ctor (Gtk.WindowType type) [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK.FormsWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <4bad12fcff0f409181b1aa48e034f579>:0 
  at BasicBoxView.GTK.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00014] in <12b4a789a2e94320a9d8929a6bfc16da>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gtk.Container' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: gtksharpglue-2
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Container.gtksharp_gtk_container_get_focus_child_offset()
  at Gtk.Container..cctor () [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Gtk.Bin..ctor (System.IntPtr raw) [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
  at Gtk.Window..ctor (Gtk.WindowType type) [0x00000] in <94f79862491c46b0bf711bc40f7608a5>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.GTK.FormsWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <4bad12fcff0f409181b1aa48e034f579>:0 
  at BasicBoxView.GTK.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00014] in <12b4a789a2e94320a9d8929a6bfc16da>:0 
spsuser@ubuntusrv:~/Desktop/Boxview/Debug$ 
----------------------------------------------------------------

$ sudo find /usr/ -name  libgtksharpglue-2*
[sudo] password for spsuser: 
/usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/libgtksharpglue-2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtksharpglue-2.so
/usr/bin/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.so
```

/usr/bin/lib/libgtksharpglue-2.la

I tried to map DLL with `/etc/mono/config`.

```
<dllmap dll="libgtksharpglue-2" target="libgtksharpglue-2.so" os="!windows"/>
```

My PATH variable referring to gtk-sharp-2.0 path.

```
spsuser@ubuntusrv:~/Desktop/Boxview/Debug$ echo $PATH
/home/spsuser/bin:/home/spsuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/cli/gtk-sharp-2.0/:/usr/bin/lib
```

Same error I'm seeing.
I googled this error, but didn't find any solution.
Even I tried to download samples from below link and build on Win. When I run these on Ubuntu it is giving same error.

https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-gtk-samples
My objective is existing Xamarin.Forms app which is running on Win, that needs to be run on Linux.
Any one who tried above link, please check and help me.

Comment: Have a look at existing SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885454/mono-on-osx-couldnt-find-gtksharpglue-2-dll) It's for OSX, but has some helpful details. I guess, that you should map not only this particular dll

Comment: Thanks Pavel Anikhouski, I had gone through above thread link. Which ever DLL errors got, I mapped those. But this error is not resolved, not sure where I'm doing mistake.  @AdrianCooney  please suggest your views on this.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your dllmap. You have `dll="libgtksharpglue-2"` with a `lib` prefix when you just want `dll="gtksharpglue-2"`

Comment: Thanks @Jester identifying, I corrected. Now it is working.